# Evolving functions in python

Tags: python, numpy, lambda, scipy, numerical-integration

## Updated Question

---

Following from my original post, with the use of @Attack68 's code, I have created a program that successfully evolved the function with a choice of multiplicative functions based on a random variable. However, now I am receiving an error saying the list indices must be integers (even though I'm fairly sure they are), I'm not sure what has happened, The code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate
x=np.linspace(0.0,1.0,100)
n=10 #iterations
d=700.0
def f(x):
    return np.sin(x)

def g(x,list_):
    return np.cos(x)*apply(x,list_)

base = [f, g]

list_ = list()
for i in range(n):
    testvar=np.random.randint(1, 100, 1)
    if testvar> 50 and i!=0:
        func_idx = 0 # choose a random operation: 0=ten, 1=inv
    else:
        func_idx= 1
    list_.append(func_idx)

    # now you have a list of indexes referencing your base functions so you can apply them:

    def apply(x,list_):
        y = 1
        for i in range(len(list_)):
            y *= base[list_[i]](x)
        return y

    print(list_)
    #testint=integrate.quad(apply(x,list_),-d,d)[0]
    #print(testint)
    print(apply(list_, x))
```

I am now getting the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64
```

I am also attempting to get this to integrate the new function after each iteration but it seems that the form of this function is not callable by scipys quad integrator, any suggestions on how to integrate the evolving function on each iteration would also be appreciated.

---

### Original:

I am creating a simulation in python where I consider a function that evolves over a loop. This function starts off defined as:

```
def f(x):
    return 1.0
```

So simply a flat distribution. After each iteration of the loop, I want the function to be redefined depending on certain (random) conditions. It could be multiplied by cos(b*x) or it could be multiplied by some function A(x), the evolution will not be the same each time due to the randomness, so I cannot simply multiply by the same value each time.

The progression in one instance could be:

f(x)----> f(x)*A(x)----> f(x)*A(x)*A(x)...

but in another instance it could be:

f(x)----> f(x)*A(x)----> f(x)*A(x)*cos(x)...

or

f(x)----> f(x)*cos(x)----> f(x)*cos(x)*cos(x)...

etc.
after each, of n iterations of this evolution, I have to compute an integral that is related to the function, so I need to essentially update the function after each iteration to be called by scipys quad integrator.

I have tried to use arrays to manipulate the distribution instead and it works as far as the function evolution goes, but upon integration, it gives the incorrect result with numpy.trapz and I cannot work out why. Sci-pys quad integrator is more accurate anyway and I had managed to get this to work previously for the first iteration only, but it requires a function based input, so without this function evolution I cannot use it.

If someone could show me if/how this function evolution is possible that'd be great. If it is not possible, perhaps someone could try to help me understand what numpy.trapz actually does so I can workout how to fix it?

Comment: It looks like you are after the Composite Design Pattern.

Comment: Show some code please. Questions of the form "my code doesn't seem to behave correctly" without any actual detail are virtually impossible to answer.

Comment: Let us assume t1=f(x), t2=f(x)*A(x), t3=f(x)*A(x)*A(x). From the question, we can understand t1,t2,t3 in your progression, how t4, t5, etc could look like is not clear. Can you please provide more info?

Comment: @quamrana. Or a list of functions with a wrapper to call them in sequence. OP is multiplying, not actually composing functions here.

Comment: @Haranadth. What are you labeling as t4 and t5?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Updated my comment. :), t4, t5 I am assuming the next elements of the sequence/progression.

Comment: As MadPhysicist says, and Attack68 illustrates, you can make a function which loops over a list of functions, multiplying the results together. However, calling that looping function will get slower & slower as the list grows. So integrating it will be a bit painful. This *might* be a situation where the use of `eval` is warranted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
class MyFunction:
    def __init__(self):
        def f1(x):
            return 1.0
        self.functions = [f1]

    def append_function(self, fn):
        self.functions.append(fn)

    def __call__(self, x):
        product = 1.0
        for f in self.functions:
            product *= f(x)
        return product
```

This object starts off as simply returning 1.0.  Later you add more functions and it returns the product of all of them.

Comment: Changed my answer to track a list of functions.

Answer (score 2):

Your description suggests your iterated values are combined through a product and are not in fact a composition of functions. A simple way of recording these is to have a set of base functions:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as int

def two(x):
    return x*2

def inv(x):
    return 1/x

base = [two, inv]

funcs = np.random.choice(base, size=10)

def apply(x, funcs):
    y = 1
    for func in funcs:
        y *= func(x)
    return y

print('function value at 1.5 ', apply(1.5, funcs))

answer = int.quad(apply, 1, 2, args=(funcs,))
print('integration over [1,2]: ', answer)
```

Comment: You don't need indices in `apply`. You can loop directly over the function list, eg `for func in base: y *= func(x)`

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, is there a way to call each and store the function after each iteration... as the second function is actually dependent on the cumulative product... i.e. if after two iterations the function was ten*inv, then inv 
 for the third iteration would be (ten*inv)**2

Comment: yes just use lists, or dicts and append new entries. Difficult to plan exactly for your use case based on the generic question but im sure its quite acheiveable

Comment: thank you, as for the integration is the function "apply" callable with scipys quad integrator or is another method required?

Comment: it is a callable function so is valid. You might need to reorder the arguments so x is first though according to the scipy quad documentation

Comment: Can this still be used with the original list format? just that the choice of function is not completely random. @Attack68

Comment: of course, but that is a simple programming concept and inserting objects into a list or sequential objects. it does not really impact my answer, you juist need to manipulate it to suit your own purpose.