# Python- np.random.choice

Tags: python, numpy, function, random

I am using the numpy.random.choice module to generate an 'array' of choices based on an array of functions:

```
def f(x):
    return np.sin(x)

def g(x):
    return np.cos(x)


base=[f, g]

funcs=np.random.choice(base,size=2)
```

This code will produce an 'array' of 2 items referencing a function from the base array.

The reason for this post is, I have printed the outcome of funcs and recieved:

```
[<function f at 0x00000225AC94F0D0> <function f at 0x00000225AC94F0D0>]
```

Clearly this returns a reference to the functions in some form, not that I understand what that form is or how to manipulate it, this is where the problem comes in. I want to change the choice of function, so that it is no longer random and instead depends on some conditions, so it might be:

```
for i in range(2):
    if testvar=='true':
        choice[i] = 0 
    if testvar== 'false':
        choice[i] = 1
```

This would return an array of indicies to be put in later function

The problem is, the further operations of the code (I think) require this previous form of function reference: [ ] as an input, instead of a simple array of 0,1 Indicies and I don't know how I can get an array of form [ ] by using if statements.

I could be completely wrong about the rest of the code requiring this input, but I don't know how I can amend it, so am hence posting it here. The full code is as follows: (it is a slight variation of code provided by @Attack68 on [Evolving functions in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59425718/evolving-functions-in-python)) It aims to store a function that is multiplied by a random function on each iteration and integrates accordingly. (I have put a comment on the code above the function that is causing the problem)

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as int

def f(x):
    return np.sin(x)

def g(x):
    return np.cos(x)

base = [f, g]

funcs = np.random.choice(base, size=2)
print(funcs)
#The below function is where I believe the [<function...>] input to be required
def apply(x, funcs):
    y = 1
    for func in funcs:
        y *= func(x)
    return y

print('function value at 1.5 ', apply(1.5, funcs))

answer = int.quad(apply, 1, 2, args=(funcs,))
print('integration over [1,2]: ', answer)
```

Here is my attempt of implementing a non-random event:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as int
import random
def f(x):
    return np.sin(x)

def g(x):
    return np.cos(x)

base = [f, g]

funcs = list()
for i in range(2):
    testvar=random.randint(0,100) #In my actual code, this would not be random but dependent on some other situation I have not accounted for here
    if testvar>50:
        func_idx = 0 # choose a np.random operation: 0=f, 1=g
    else:
        func_idx= 1
    funcs.append(func_idx)
#funcs = np.random.choice(base, size=10)
print(funcs)
def apply(x, funcs):
    y = 1
    for func in funcs:
        y *= func(x)
    return y

print('function value at 1.5 ', apply(1.5, funcs))

answer = int.quad(apply, 1, 2, args=(funcs,))
print('integration over [1,2]: ', answer)
```

This returns the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: I'm unclear on how `testvar` and `choice` fit in your overall goal.

Comment: `base` is a list, not an array. Why have you decided to use numpy.random instead of the Python random module?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. In the main code, func is an array with 2 elements. so I would want to loop over the if statements twice to give back two elements which would correspond to the index of base array, i.e. for choice=0: base[0] returns function f(x) @busybear

Comment: @wwii I had gotten the code from another thread so was just basing it on that

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking, or what you expect to happen vs what it is actually doing. How is `apply` deficient?

Comment: I'm still unclear on how `testvar` fits in. Its value needs to change somehow for the if statements to be relevant. But it seems you are trying to define `func` as a list of functions based on `choice`, correct? Something like `func = [base[n] for n in choice]`?

Comment: apply works perfectly fine in the main code, with the random elements. But I am trying to remove the random elements and if I pass a list through apply it gives this error: 'TypeError: 'int' object is not callable' I will edit the original question to show the code that generates this error

Comment: @busybear I have added an extra section of code in my OP that may help clear up what I am trying to do

Comment: You are trying to refactor your original code that operates on a list of randomly chosen functions to a version that operates with random indices which correspond to items in a list of functions?

Comment: I agree with the other commenters, this is still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If: You are trying to refactor your original code that operates on a list of randomly chosen functions to a version that operates with random indices which correspond to items in a list of functions. Refactor `apply`.

```
def apply(x,indices,base=base):
    y = 1
    for i in indices:
        f = base[i]
        y *= f(x)
    return y
```

---

> ...this returns a reference to the functions in some form, not that I understand what that form is or how to manipulate it...

Functions are objects, the list contains a reference to the objects themselves. They can be used by either assigning them to a name then calling them or indexing the list and calling the object:

```
>>> def f():
...     return 'f'

>>> def g():
...     return 'g'

>>> a = [f,g]
>>> q = a[0]
>>> q()
'f'
>>> a[1]()
'g'
>>> for thing in a:
    print(thing())

f
g
```

Or you can pass them around:

```
>>> def h(thing):
...     return thing()

>>> h(a[1])
'g'
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use your function `apply` as-is, you need to keep your input a list of functions. Instead of providing a list of indices, you can use those indices to create your list of functions.

Instead of `apply(1.5, funcs)`, try:

```
apply(1.5, [base(n) for n in funcs])
```